# mvim closing last tab want not to close window

Tags: vim, macvim

I am just getting start with mvim coming from e-texteditor on Windows. One little annoyance (for me) is that when I use the cmd+w to close tabs, if the last tab is closed the window of mvim is also closed, is there any chance that I can keep that window open with one empty tab in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~/.gvimrc` file (*not* your `.vimrc`; and create one if it doesn't exist already), add:

```
macm File.Close key=<nop>
nnoremap <silent> <D-w> <Esc>:bd<CR>
```

The first line unmaps the `<D-w>` menu binding so you can remap it. The second  maps `<D-w>` to close each vim-window one at a time, which will close the tab if it is the last vim-window in the tab, and will leave the OS window open on the last remaining tabpage. The caveat is that it will also cycle through all hidden buffers in that last window, closing each in turn (though you could use `<D-S-w>` at this point to close the OS window at once). c.f. `:help :bd`. If you don't desire this behavior, you could use this instead:

```
nnoremap <silent> <D-w> <Esc>:tabclose<CR>
```

Which is more strictly what you were asking for. c.f. `:help :tabclose`

Duplicate the mapping replacing `nnoremap` with `inoremap` if you want it to work in insert mode, too.

Comment: Thanks for the details! I think I am going with the second form

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this [script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147). It does something similar to what you have mentioned. Using Araxia's mapping for Command-W you can replace the scripts commands to Cmd-w.